# How to increment a value without any for loop but based on number of times the file is run in PHP

Tags: php, file, increment, stat

I have a script which, when it runs, creates a new file in some directory. While creating a new file it checks if the file exists:

- If it exists it should append `1` to the file name
- If another file has same name it should increment and append `2`.

```
$filecount = 0;
if (! file_exists ( SOME_DIR . $fileName )) {
    echo "not there";
    //so save normally
} else {
    echo "there";
    $fileName  = $fileName."_" .$file_count++.".txt";
    // save with number at the end
}
```

Currently, when the file is run multiple times it is only saving with number for the first time, as the variable `$filecount` is again set to `0`.

Is there any work around to increment `filename` when its name is repeated?

Comment: Is it really necessary to append numbers in that order- 0, 1, 2... ? In case you want to create a file by appending something which makes it unique, you could concat `uniqid()` or `rand()` or `time()` with the `$fileName`. That will generate unique filenames every time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like this

```
<?php
define('SOME_DIR', '');

$fileName = 'file';
if (! file_exists ( SOME_DIR . $fileName.'.txt' )) {
    echo "not there";
    //so save normally
}
else{
    $files = glob(SOME_DIR.$fileName.'_*.txt');
    $counter = count($files)+1;
    echo "there";
    $fileName  = $fileName."_" .$counter.".txt";
    echo $fileName;
    // save with number at the end
}
```

Tested, working well for me

Answer (score 0):

You need to store somewhere the number of runs of your script. If you are already writing files I would use an plain text file to store the number of runs.

Other options is to use a timestamp as file name deduplicator.

Comment: increment is not merely based on file runs, but increment should be appended to file names if they are duplicate

Comment: In any case if you have stored the "runs count" you can use when you need it. The key point here is that you need to know the number of times that you have run the script and for that it must be stored in some persistent storage.  Disk, session, database... As you are using already file writes, i would use one more to store that data.

Answer (score 0):

```
define('SOME_DIR', __DIR__ . '/');
$basename = 'test.txt';
$path = SOME_DIR . $basename;

// Consider clearing stat cache before using `file_exists` and similar
// functions that run `stat`, or `lstat` system calls under the hood.
clearstatcache(true, $path);

if (file_exists($path)) {
  $filename = pathinfo($basename, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
  $ext      = pathinfo($basename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

  $files = glob(SOME_DIR . "${filename}_[0-9]*.${ext}", GLOB_BRACE);

  $basename = sprintf(
    '%s_%d.%s',
    $filename,
    (count($files) + 1),
    $ext
  );

  $path = SOME_DIR . $basename;
}

// Replace with your logic
touch($path);
```